# Show that $\int_0^{1/2} {1\over x^2-x+1}dx$ = $\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am working on the representation of functions as power series in my book.
So I figure this problem has something to do with representing it as a power series but I am getting lost. Here is what I have...

$x^2-x+1 = (x-1/2)^2+3/4$ So I want to show $\int_0^{1/2} {1\over (x-1/2)^2+3/4}dx$ = $\pi\over{3\sqrt3}$

$x=\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)\tan\theta+{1/2}$

$dx=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}(\sec^2\theta)d\theta$

$\int_0^{1/2} {1\over (x-1/2)^2+3/4}dx$= $2\sqrt3$ $\int_{\tan^{-1}\frac{-1}{\sqrt3}}^0d\theta \neq \left(\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}\right)$

Comment: You should first do $u=x-1/2$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_0 \frac{1}{x^2-x+1}dx$$
$$=\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_0 \frac{1}{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}dx$$
$$=\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_0 \frac{1}{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2}dx$$
Using the formula $\int \frac1{a^2+x^2}dx=\frac1a\tan^{-1}\frac xa+C$, we get
$$=\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\tan ^{-1}(\frac{x-\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}})|^{\frac{1}{2}}_0$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int^{\frac12}_{0}\frac1{x^2-x+1}dx$$
$b^2=4ac$ so $1=4.1.c$, $c=\frac14$. And then put $x-\frac12=u.$
$$\int^{0}_{-\frac12}\frac1{u^2+\frac34}du$$ 
Now by using $$\int \frac1{a^2+x^2}dx=\frac1a\tan^{-1}\frac xa+C$$
We get $$[\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}\frac{2u}{\sqrt3}]^{0}_{-\frac12}=0-(\frac2{\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}-\frac1{\sqrt3})=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}}$$
**PROOF OF $\int \frac1{a^2+x^2}dx=\frac1a\tan^{-1}\frac xa+C$:** 
Substitute $x=a\tan\theta;dx=a\sec^2\theta d\theta$
$$=\frac a{a^2}\int\frac1{1}d\theta$$
$$=\frac1a\theta=\boxed{\frac1a\tan^{-1}\frac xa+C}$$